# Objective C - Ajax freezes screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ajax, ipad

I am new to iOS world and to programming in Objective - C too.
I am doing a basic iOS app for iPad and iPhone with a initial login screen.
Sometimes it's working fine but others it's just freezes the screen and block the app execution when I click the login button. I think the ajax process it's the problem but like I said I'm new to this...

This is the code where I am calling the API to check the credentials:

```
        NSString   *password   = @"XXXXXXXXXX";
        NSString   *joinString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",@"http://www.example.com?view=checks&tmpl=json&c=",input,@"&p=",password,@"&onlymail"];
        NSLog(@"calling: %@", joinString);

        NSURL      *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:joinString];
        NSData     *data       = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSString   *ret        = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSString *returned = [ret stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        NSLog(@"returned: %@", returned);

        if([returned length] != 0 && ![returned isEqual:@""] && ![returned isEqual:NULL])
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection Successful: %@", ret);
            return returned;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
            return @"";
        }
```

UPDATED CODE

```
        NSString   *password   = @"XXXXXXXXX";
        NSString   *joinString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@",@"http://www.example.com/index.php?view=checks&tmpl=json&c=",input,@"&p=",password,@"&onlymail"];
        NSURL      *url        = [NSURL URLWithString:joinString];
       [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


        [[[NSURLSession sharedSession]
           dataTaskWithURL:url
           completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
        {
              if (data != nil && error == nil)
              {
                   NSString *returned = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                   if([returned length] != 0 && ![returned isEqual:@""] && ![returned isEqual:NULL])
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Connection Successful: %@", returned);

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");

                   }
              }
              else
              {
                  NSLog(@"error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
              }

         }] resume];
```

I know my code is not perfect, so please give me some advice about to **resolve this issue** or just to improve my best practices in iOS development.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Don't make synchronous network requests on main thread.

Comment: Thank you Kreiri, I will check it if works.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

The above call is synchronous, and if your code is running in main thread - the thread will be blocked and UI will freeze until the above call returns.
You should always try to perform long-running (or network related) operations asynchronously, in your case I'd look at:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession]
  dataTaskWithURL:url
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error) {
            // handle response

        }] resume];
```

Comment: Thank you VKofman, I am comming from Android world and there is the same issue with big processes to perform in the main thread. I thought in iOS was different but not...

Comment: Still freeze the screen when click login button. Maybe I have to move the code into another class different than the main .m file? Thanks anyway...

Comment: I ended up with a temporal solution:    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];  session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 2;    This will block the  app only 2 seconds...